# Apache cordova for visual studio does not update iOS plaftorm files during build

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have just started an ionic based project within Visual Studio 2015 community edition and I am having trouble running the ripple emulator for iOS. It was working fine until I added a few new files to the project (angular translate and some of my own). Now when I go to

platforms\ios\www

I can see that the files I added are never being copied. Everything is working fine in the android platform folder though.
Is there a file that controls which files should be copied during build / deploy?

Comment: what error you saw? Better to have the build log in diagnostic mode. In VS, Tools menu-> Options-> Project and Solutions->Build and Run -> change MSBuild output verbosity to diagnostics

Comment: There are no errors. It simply doesn't update the files.

Comment: What happens if you perform a Clean and then Rebuild?

Comment: Could you please share a repro that can let us fully understand the issue? Does the issue cause the app fail to run? If you manually delete the platforms folder and build the project again, can you find the files get copied?

Comment: Deleting the platforms folder causes VS to redeploy everything and it works fine. I haven't encountered the issue again! I don't know what to say :|

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned in the comments, deleting the `platforms` folder forces Visual Studio to copy those files again, and it should build/deploy with the updated files.

Note that you may run into issues with some plugins not being able to be restored when you delete the whole `platforms` folder.

I suggest you just delete the following folder, for Android: `platforms\android\assets\www`